# clientHeight is not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a parent and child element and sets the parent element height as 100%.
When i check the child element height it show some value in chrome browser.
But in IE browser it shown as 0. what i made wrong and how can i get the height value.

```
<div id='parent'>  
  <div id="child"></div>  
</div>
/* Styles go here */
#parent{
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  display:grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  align-items:stretch;
  position:relative;
}
```

i have used `clientHeight` to find the element height.
**document.getElementById(''child").clientHeight**

Sample Link https://jsfiddle.net/zc39px72/

Comment: you can use jQuery?

Comment: no. I am using javascript

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code that you are using? The fiddle doesn’t contain any.

Comment: document.getElementById(''child").clientHeight

Comment: I think that this article can help you to know what is happening here. https://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how the grid will act and repeat, cause you are using grid to make the child element to get the full width and height of its container.Also you need to get the element heigh by using `offsetHeight` (or width using `offsetWidth`).

Check the following snippet:

```js
var child = document.getElementById('child');
child.innerHTML = 'My height is: ' + child.offsetHeight;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#parent{
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 1, 1fr );
  -ms-grid-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 1, 100% );
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```